# javascript nextsibling function

Tags: javascript, html, parent, nextsibling

```
<html>
<body>
<script language="JavaScript">
function function1() {
   var m = document.getElementById("myNodeOne").nextSibling;
   m.innerHTML = "asdfsdf";
}
</script>
<p>This PARAGRAPH has two nodes, 
    <b id="myNodeOne">Node One</b>, and 
    <b id="myNodeTwo">Node Two</b>.
</p>
<p></p>
<button onclick="function1();">Node One has a Next Sibling</button>
</body>
</html>
```

This should print "asdfsdf" in second paragraph tag. But its not working.

Comment: As others have stated. This link looks useful:

http://v3.thewatchmakerproject.com/journal/329/finding-html-elements-using-javascript-nextsibling-and-previoussibling

Comment: Note that nextSibling is not a function, it's a property.

Comment: @Wasim Check [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38436741/2404470) if it helps

Answer (score 16):

Try to use `nextElementSibling` instead of `nextSibling`

```
function function1() {
var m = document.getElementById("myNodeOne").nextElementSibling;
m.innerHTML = "asdfsdf";
}
```

It works because it only fetches HTML elements.

Answer (score 4):

A couple of issues:

- if you store in the variable m a DOM element and then you set any m
  property, the DOM will not be affected at all.
- document.getElementById("myNodeOne").nextSibling is not myNode2, but
  the text element `, and` between the two nodes.

Try this:

```
function function1() {
   document.getElementById("myNodeOne").parentNode.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = "asdfsdf";
}​
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/dCL8C/5/)

Answer (score 2):

**nextSibling**
returns the node immediately following **this** node. If there is no such node, it returns null.

Since the immediate following node is a TEXT_NODE, it returns that.  Here are all the nodeTypes:

```
Node.ELEMENT_NODE == 1
Node.ATTRIBUTE_NODE == 2
Node.TEXT_NODE == 3
Node.CDATA_SECTION_NODE == 4
Node.ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE == 5
Node.ENTITY_NODE == 6
Node.PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE == 7
Node.COMMENT_NODE == 8
Node.DOCUMENT_NODE == 9
Node.DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE == 10
Node.DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE == 11
Node.NOTATION_NODE == 12
```

Here is an example of how to filter by node type:

```
function function1() {
   var m = document.getElementById("myNodeOne").nextSibling;

  if (m.nodeType != 1) {
    m = m.nextSibling;
  }
   m.innerHTML = "asdfsdf";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because next sibling of your first div is text node: `, and`

Text nodes doesn't have `innerHTML` attribute

You need to use:

```
document.getElementById("myNodeOne").nextSibling.nextSibling
```

Comment: This prints it in the second bold element, he said the second paragraph element.

Answer (score 1):

You have to take into account the text, which is present between your `<b>...</b>` tags, and is correctly returned as a nextSibling of the first of them

```
function function1() {
   var m = document.getElementById("myNodeOne");
   m.nextSibling.nextSibling.innerHTML = "asdfsdf";
}
```

​

Comment: It's better if you only provide the part you're updating... otherwise we have to compare every line of your code with the original code to find out what is different!

Answer (score 1):

looks like the next sibling for your myNodeOne is ", and" if you want to get to the next one you'll have to put:

```
var m = document.getElementById("myNodeOne").nextSibling;
    m.nextSibling.innerHTML= "asdfsdf";
```