# this.nextSibling not working

Tags: javascript, siblings

I expect the following code to alert "out"

```
<input type=text onfocus="alert(this.nextSibling.id)" />
<output id="out">this is output</output>
```

But it alerts undefined
WHY?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

`nextSibling` selects the very next sibling node of the element. The very next node can also be a `textNode` which doesn't have an `id` property, hence you get the `undefined` value. As the other answer suggests you could use the `nextElementSibling` property which refers to the next sibling node that has `nodeType` of `1` (i.e. an Element object) or remove the hidden characters between the elements.

Note that IE8 doesn't support the `nextElementSibling` property.

Comment: but in my code there is no nodes between  the inout element and output  and i don't see ant hidden characters

Comment: @moroccan_dev Please check this fiddle, and open the console to see the logged node. http://jsfiddle.net/khcxjta5/

Comment: @moroccan_dev hidden characters are something that you can't see since they are hidden. In this case, they're the newline characters.

Answer (score 11):

Try this:

```
alert(this.nextElementSibling.id);
```

**NOTE:**
The `nextSibling` property returns the node immediately following the specified node, in the same tree level.

The `nextElementSibling` read-only property returns the element immediately following the specified one in its parent's children list, or null if the specified element is the last one in the list.

Answer (score 5):

**Why you have this problem**

`nextSibling` selects the next sibling node of the element. In your case you have a text node as a next node because you have a new line between your element nodes. Each text node between element nodes will be selected as next node and this nodes don't have an `id` property.

To prevent this we can use 2 ways:

**Solution 1:**

We delete a *new lines*, *all of whitespaces*, *comment nodes* or *other text nodes* and then we can use `nextSibling`:

```html
<input type="button" value="get next sibling value" onclick="console.log(this.nextSibling.value)"><input type="text" value="txt 1">
```

**Solution 2:**

We use instead of `nextSibling` the `nextElementSibling` property:

```html
<input type="button" value="get next sibling value" onclick="console.log(this.nextElementSibling.value)">
<input type="text" value="txt 1">
```

The `nextElementSibling` property returns the element immediately following the specified one in its parent's children list, or null if the specified element is the last one in the list.

In the case if some browser like IE8 doesn't support the `nextElementSibling` property we can use a polyfill (it should be placed before your code):

```
if(!('nextElementSibling' in document.documentElement))
{
    Object.defineProperty(Element.prototype, 'nextElementSibling',
    {
        get: function()
        {
            var e = this.nextSibling;
            while (e && e.nodeType !== 1)
                e = e.nextSibling;

            return e;
        }
    });
}
```

**Relevant links:**

- **[`Node.nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)**
- **[`NonDocumentTypeChildNode.nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NonDocumentTypeChildNode/nextElementSibling)**

Answer (score -1):

> Assuming that you can use `jQuery`

Note that `this.nextSibling` [might not work in IE specifically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38407749/dxtooltip-not-working-in-ie-working-in-chrome#comment64266841_38407749)

The `jQuery` alternative for `this.nextSibling` is `$(this).next()`

Comment: Why would you post a jQuery answer to a question that asks explicitly for a JavaScript answer and, nowhere, suggests that jQuery is either being used or is an option? Especially after eighteen months (as I write this)?

Comment: @DavidThomas , i totally agree , i know its old but i hate when i ask question about JavaScript and someone suggest a Prefabricated library , i mean how we can learn JavaScript if we being lazy and use the already-made scripts everytime , we can suggest others to use jQuery if they dont want to learn the true javascript.