# dxTooltip not working in IE, working in Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, internet-explorer, devextreme

I have got a `dxChart`:

```
            var chart = $("#chartContainer4").dxChart();
```

of which I’m taking the legend rectangles:

```
            var PayerLegendBoxes = $("#chartContainer4 .dxc-legend g rect");
```

And using `dxTooltip` for showing on mouse hover.

```
            PayerLegendBoxes.each(function () {



                var nextElementHTML = this.nextSibling.innerHTML;

                var currElementTip = nextElementHTML + "tip";

                var currElement = this;



                var title = chart.append("<span style='display:none;' id=" + currElementTip + ">" + nextElementHTML + "</span>");



                var tooltipSimple = $("#" + currElementTip).dxTooltip({

                    target: currElement,

                }).dxTooltip("instance");



                $(currElement).unbind().hover(function () {

                    tooltipSimple.toggle()

                });



            });
```

This is working fine in Chrome but not in IE.

Is there a bug for cross browser functionality?

Comment: What IE version do you use?

Comment: @Sergey IE10 specifically

Comment: Do you have any errors in the browser console?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like the problem is in this line:

```
var nextElementHTML = this.nextSibling.innerHTML;
```

`nextSibling.innerHTML` returns `undefined` in IE. So, I suggest you use something like this:

```
// jQuery provides a "cross-browser" way here
var nextElementHTML = $(this).next().text();
```

And one more correction for this line:

```
var currElementTip = nextElementHTML + "tip";
```

`nextElementHTML` can sometimes contain a white space symbol. So, you should sanitize it:

```
var currElementTip = (nextElementHTML + "tip").replace(/\s/g, "_");
```

The updated sample is here - http://jsfiddle.net/5y8f4zt0/