# nextSibling returns null while sibling exists

Tags: javascript

In this part of code, why `nextSibling` returns null ?

```js
const formIt = () => {
  const titles = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
  document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
  titles.forEach(title => {
    console.log(title.nextSibling);
    let p = title.nextSibling; //Returns null
    let pWrapper = document.createElement('div');
    pWrapper.appendChild(p);
document.getElementById('content').appendChild(pWrapper);
  });
};

formIt();
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  <h1>...</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <h1>...</h1>
  <p>...</p>
  <h1>...</h1>
  <p>...</p>
</div>
```

Comment: It returns null because there isn't a next sibling. Obviously this isn't the case in your example so perhaps there's an h1 elsewhere on the page.

Comment: @nlta did you try the snippet? There's no other `h1` in the code. This is it. There's three `h1` elements with three `p` elements next to them. So obviously they are siblings.

Comment: There are no DOM elements left after you use `document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On line 3 you set the `innerHTML` of `content` to an empty string.

That removes all the h1 and p elements from the DOM.

They aren’t siblings after that.

——

Fiddle with `innerHTML` **after** you have finished the loop.

Answer (score 1):

Simply because, by the time the forEach() runs, you've removed all those objects from the DOM:

```
document.getElementById('content').innerHTML = '';
```

...so they no longer have any siblings.

Comment: Ah, yes, @quentin beat me to the right answer while I was busy typing.  Cheers!

Answer (score -1):

There are two *properties* to iterate on `Node`s or elements:

1. [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling)
2. [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/nextElementSibling)

See the note at documentation of [`nextSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/nextSibling):

> Note: Browsers **insert Text nodes** into a document **to represent whitespace** in the source markup. Therefore a node obtained, for example, using `Node.firstChild` or `Node.previousSibling` may refer to a whitespace text node **rather than the actual element the author intended to get**.
>
> [..]
>
> You can use `Element.nextElementSibling` to obtain the **next element skipping any whitespace** nodes, other between-element text, or comments.
> (emphasis mine)

See similar question:

- [javascript nextsibling function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11346765/javascript-nextsibling-function)

#### Example

```js
const headings = document.querySelectorAll('h1');
console.log("headings (count):", headings.length);

let firstHeading = headings[0];
console.log("first h1 nextSibling (data):", firstHeading.nextSibling.data);
console.log("first h1 nextElementSibling (data):", firstHeading.nextElementSibling.data);

let secondHeading = headings[1];
console.log("second h1 nextSibling (data):", secondHeading.nextSibling.data);
console.log("second h1 nextElementSibling (data):", secondHeading.nextElementSibling.data);
```

```html
<div id='content'>
  <h1>heading_1</h1>text_1
  <p>paragraph_1</p>
  <h1>heading_2</h1>
  <p>paragraph_2</p>
</div>
```